# ImageMagick quantizeImage 100x slower on newer versions

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am using [$imagick->quantizeImage](https://phpimagick.com/Imagick/quantizeImage) in order to reduce image size as it only contains some lines in same color (like a mini chart). But with `ImageMagick 7.0.10-10 Q16 x86_64 2020-05-12 (alt-ImageMagick-7.0.10.10-1.el6.x86_64)` this function is about 100x slower than it was in previous versions.

Example with 100 images:

- without `$imagick->quantizeImage(4, \Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, false, false);`
  [image]
- with `$imagick->quantizeImage(4, \Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, false, false);`
  [image]

How could I get same results while still having similar execution time as before?

Comment: Please ask on the ImageMagick forum. The ImageMagick developers do not regularly monitor this forum. IM 7 is HDRI compiled and thus will be slower than IM 6. You could try disabling HDRI and recompiling or disable OpenMP and see if that helps. Have you tested directly with ImageMagick without going through Imagick? Perhaps the issue is with Imagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that turning on dither flag fixes this, e.g., use

`$imagick->quantizeImage(4, \Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, true, false);`

instead of

`$imagick->quantizeImage(4, \Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, false, false);`

This seems to me like a bug when dither is disabled.